# Log entries are missing after checking out a previous commit

Tags: git

After rolling back to a previous commit in git using:

```
git checkout <commit hash>
```

and then perform a `git log`, all my log entries after the commit I just checked out are missing.

How do I get a listing of all commits once I've checked out a previous commit? I need to checkout the latest and go forward in time.

Comment: `git log` shows the log up to your current commit. Can you explain your usecase a bit more? If you are just undoing a commit because it was wrong, you should use `git revert <commit hash>`.

Comment: I simply want to take a look at some older code. Not looking to roll back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git log` shows the log from the current HEAD. Assuming the branch you want to see the log of is "master", to see the "full" log again you can do either of the following:

Checkout the branch and then run git log:

```
git checkout master
git log
```

Pass a reference to `git log` to use as the HEAD:

```
git log master
```

and then have a reference of "future" commits to checkout instead.

If you want to see a log of the changes to Git references (e.g. branches and HEAD), use `git reflog`.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout <commit hash>` is not rolling back.

You might want to try `git reset --hard <commit hash>` if you want to "roll back" commits.

If you want log of the master branch ( if master is the branch that you were in), you have to do:

```
git log master
```

Currently, you checked out a particular commit and log will show commits till that commit only and not commits after that.

Also, if you had done this checkout to make commits over this commit, stop! You are in a detached HEAD state and it is mean't only for commit inspection. You can go back to master using `git checkout master` or you can even do `git checkout -`

Comment: I'm not actually looking to roll back, I just wanted to take a look at some code that existed at a previous point in time. I just couldn't get back after that.

Answer (score 1):

please see `git reflog show` message.It helped me recover old local changes.